# change WebDav folder on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, webdav

I'm sure this can be done but however I could not figure out to set this up. I enabled WebDav on the tomcat server in the web.xml. Right now, when I access WebDav, I mount the 'ROOT' folder of the 'webapps' folder of tomcat. Is there a way to change that folder to for example C:\MyData instead of storing all data in the root folder of tomcat?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: In case anyone reaches here from Google due to similar wording but a very different intent, the answer you're looking for is: `Tomcat.setBaseDir("/")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you edited the `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/web.xml` to enable WebDAV

Instead, you can enable the `WebDAVServlet` only for a particular webapp by editing it's own `web.xml`

Model your new webapp (say, mynewapp) on the lines of the docs webapp already present under `/webapps`.

All you need are the `mynewapp/WEB-INF/web.xml` to be present with the right `servlet` definition and `servlet-mapping` tags

Note: This will be accessible as

`http://<url:port>/mynewapp`

If you want this accessible without the `/mynewapp` suffix, you'll have to edit conf/server.xml and add a `<Context>` with `path="/"`

Comment: Thanks. I just did that. The only problem left now is that when I connect through the file system, I have to provide a username and pw, which is perfectly fine. However, when I enter the link into the browser, I see all files...

Comment: Okay, also to add, you can point this to a folder outside Tomcat, like C:\MyDocs by modifying the `docBase` attribute in the Context. The whole folder from under `webapps\mynewapp` then belongs in the new path

Comment: would that solve my problem that my folder is right now accessible through the web without a pw?

Comment: For that, you'll have to make this folder readonly, make a separate URL for editing and **secure access to both URLs in web.xml** using a `security-constraint` See more at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/servlets/WebdavServlet.html

Comment: sorry for my bad knowledge in this field, but I set the directory to read only then people can still see the content right? Actually I don't want that the content is visible through the web at all. I just want to have a network storage :)

Comment: @mkn: Are you sure you really want WebDAV then? WebDAV implies the file system is available over the `http` protocol, so the user can modify this from a browser. you seem to need a shared network storage for users to pick up and drop files? This doesn't need to be on Tomcat

Comment: Well it is of course a nice feature when you can also see your files over https (then can you look at your files on the iphone for example). But the right now I'm a bit concerned about the security (I still couldn't set a password protection for viewing the data over https)

Comment: @mkn: The simple way to go is enable and test security on the examples webapp like so http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html#Example_Application and then replciate the same into your WebDAV app